# combining two strings with least code

Tags: c#, string

I have 2 strings.  I want to combine the two strings as long as the number of characters of the combined string are 20 or less.  If the combined length is great than 20 I want to truncate the first string until the combined length is 20.  The second string will never be more than 2 characters.

This is easy to do.  But, I'm looking for short, elegant code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string s1 = "some_string";
string s2 = "AB";

string s3 = s1.Substring(0, Math.Min(s1.Length, 20 - s2.Length)) + s2;
```

Answer (score 1):

With a couple of extension methods:

```
public static string Truncate(this string value, int len) {
   if (value.Length <= len) {
       return value;
   }
   return value.Substring(0, len);
}

public static string Combine(this string first, string second, int maxLen) {
   return first.Truncate(maxLen - second.Length) + second;
}
```

Then you can call it like

```
str1.Combine("xx", 20);
```

Comment: Not sure this passes the requirement of being "short"

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = (str1.Length + str2.Length > 20) ? 
(str1.Substring(0, 20-str2.Length) + str2) : 
(str1 + str2)
```

Comment: @SaeedAmiri Read the question. Str2 is never greater than length 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string s1 = "12341324";
        string s2 = "jksand9n3";
        string combined = s1.Length+s2.Length >20 ? s1.Substring(0, 20 - s2.Length) + s2 : s1+s2;
```

Comment: If s1.Length < 20-s2.Length, this will fail

Answer (score 0):

```
string s3 = s1.Length + s2.Length <= 20 ? s1 + s2 : s1.Remove(20 - s2.Length) + s2;
```